# Why add resistors to a Transistor Vin and GND

Tags: arduino-uno, transistors, infrared

I am following a tutorial where the author uses an infrared sensor  (L-51ROPT1D1 on the left) as an input to an arduino GPIO. I am not using the emittor on the right, I am only using the receiver to count infrared light pulses.

I understand that here a transistor (2SC1815 with 1.Emittor 2.Collector 3.Base) is used so that when infrared light is received, arduino receives a signal with the full 5V. Here are my questions:

1. Why use a 1k resistor between the sensor and the transistor input ?
2. Why use a 10k resistor between the emittor and GPIO/GND ?

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: Please provide data sheet links to the devices you talk about. Draw a proper schematic too. I'm aware that this was migrated but over here EEs use schematics and not cartoons.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: I modified this answer to become more accurate

I’m using an iPhone to answer this so pardon my drawing.

To answer your questions it helps to draw a schematic of your circuit. See image shown below.

I believe the intent of 1k resistor was to limit base current  to transistor when phototransistor sensor L-51ROPT1D1 is fully on. Also 1k is there to prevent BJT from becoming a RF oscillator. You can use a lower value for base resistor Ranging from 50 to 1k ohm

Purpose of 10k resistor is to provide a output voltage when transistor 2SC1815 is conducting current. Current through emitter Ie will produce Voltage when a resistor is used.

Note: If that 10k was placed between collector and supply voltage And emitter terminal ground then the base resistor of 1k or higher would be needed to limit base current and prevent base from becoming Vcc.

[image]

Comment: Note that with the schematic shown, the Arduino will not receive a full 5V signal when IR light is received.  And the purpose of the 10 Kohm resistor is to ensure that the Arduino sees a low signal when the IR light is off.  Without that resistor the Arduino would have a floating input.  With or without the resistor the Arduino would see a high voltage (though not 5 V) when the IR light is on.

Comment: Good work for a phone (puts plenty to shame) but you haven't really explained why the 1k is needed especially as the BJT is operating as an emitter follower.

Comment: @andy aka, if you know more about why 1k is there I’d like to know. Only reason I see it there is to prevent 5V from directly going to base. But then I realize now it use in emitter follower so then it only really is important if that 10k was in collector.

Comment: @Andy aka, better explanation now?

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment to @Leoman12, but I am a new contributor and haven't yet earned the 50 reputation points I need to be able to comment!

Another benefit of the base input resistor is a bit of insurance against the dreaded emitter-follower oscillations. Just a little bit of parasitic capacitance at the emitter terminal could lead to such oscillations without a base input resistor. Emitter-followers should generally be driven through a base resistance of at least 50-100 Ohms to stay out of trouble. One wouldn't need as much as 1k, but it also doesn't hurt either in this case, so it is a fine choice.

Comment: Yeah 1k ohm is over kill.

Comment: Looked at another post where they used a resistor 50 ohm to 1k to suppress oscillations.